# Grid tile Design

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to replicate this pen:[1]: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/zNBOYG
I've use the grid concept but I'm new to it so Grid Tile/item design is not accurate.
My code is as follows:-

```css
/*Base */

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

*,
html {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Typography*/

li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.welcome-section>p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/* layout */

nav {
  text-align: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.projects-gird {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.project-tile {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.project-tile span {
  display: none;
}

.project-tile p:hover span {
  color: orange;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/*Decoration*/

nav {
  background-color: #BE3144;
}

li {
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #5A7384;
}

.welcome-section {
  background-color: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.welcome-section>p {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}

.projects-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  background-color: #8878c3;
}

.projects-section-header {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid white;
}

.project-tile p {
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="projects" class="projects-section">
  <h2 class="projects-section-header">These are some of my projects</h2>
  <div class="projects-grid">
    <div class="project-tile">
      <a href="#welcome-section"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/JnPffRyN/project-fiddle.png">
        <p>
          <span>&#60;</span> work1
          <span>/&#62;</span>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="project-tile">
      <a href="#welcome-section"><img src="#">
        <p>
          <span>&#60;</span> work1
          <span>/&#62;</span>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

As you can see the result, there is a space between img and p elements and the tile design is also not accurate.Also if I want to fit two tiles in a row what should be the arguments to minmax()function .

please help me with this (Note: margin:0 has no effect)

Comment: The codepen seems to not exist

Comment: Check it now @Loi Nguyen Huynh

Comment: I don't know why, it's kinda weird but when I run on my local machine with VSCode, there's no space https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE4Vx.png, but when running on the Stack snippet, there's space:

Comment: oh yeah it''s weird.

Comment: And btw, you might misspelled `.projects-grid` with `.projects-gird`

Comment: Can you tell me how to reduce the size of a tile to fit two tiles

Comment: you should give us example to help you, write your html divs and after it will be easier for us here to write the correct code or guide for you.

Comment: @AkhilRaj Your problem is not about *size*, you misspelled the word `.projects-**grid**` in your css with `.projects-**gird**`, so the style wasn't applied as you expected.

Comment: Actually yeah , thanks for the help. How much time would it take to master responsive design .

Comment: I haven't mastered yet so I don't know. Not if sure Midz knows. Please consider giving me an upvote, you now have enough 15+ reputation to upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason there's a margin between then img and the p tag is the the img tag is not floated, if you use the following code:

```
img {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
}
```

the margin should be gone.

hope this help

Comment: Oh ok .But p and Img don't have inline-block or tile for that matter.Link is fixed now

Comment: use float:left with the img and the margin will be gone.

Comment: ok float where exactly? Also if have seen the codepen could you please tell me how to replicate that design

Comment: img {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
}

Comment: great! its fixed .Could please eloborate what happened on float left;

Comment: The float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow

read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

I know one way to make it work is to add this, your `img` was `display: inline` by default:

```
.project-tile img {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
/*Base */

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

*,
html {
  margin: 0;
}


/* Typography*/

li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.welcome-section>p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/* layout */

nav {
  text-align: right;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.welcome-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.projects-gird {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.project-tile {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.project-tile img {
  display: block;
}

.project-tile span {
  display: none;
}

.project-tile p:hover span {
  color: orange;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 200;
}


/*Decoration*/

nav {
  background-color: #BE3144;
}

li {
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: #5A7384;
}

.welcome-section {
  background-color: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.welcome-section>p {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}

.projects-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4rem 2rem;
  background-color: #8878c3;
}

.projects-section-header {
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid white;
}

.project-tile p {
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

img {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="projects" class="projects-section">
  <h2 class="projects-section-header">These are some of my projects</h2>
  <div class="projects-grid">
    <div class="project-tile">
      <a href="#welcome-section"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/JnPffRyN/project-fiddle.png">
        <p>
          <span>&#60;</span> work1
          <span>/&#62;</span>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="project-tile">
      <a href="#welcome-section"><img src="#">
        <p>
          <span>&#60;</span> work1
          <span>/&#62;</span>
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```